# How to close the Angular dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular dialog in one function i want to close in DeleteIndicatorConfirm function. How I Can do this??

```
 $scope.indicatoritems = this.item3;
    var modalInstance = ngDialog.openConfirm({
           template: 'modaldeleteindicator',
           className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
           scope: $scope,


       });
    }

$scope.DeleteIndicatorConfirm = function () {

};
```

Comment: This one ~ http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Phill should work but your var

```
var modalInstance = ...;
```

Has to go outside the function so you can access it in the other function.

Or you can always do

```
$scope.DeleteIndicatorConfirm = function () {
    ngDialog.closeAll();
};
```

Comment: It is outside the function or at least it appears to be (there's an extra `}` in OP's code but I don't know what it matches if anything)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you should be able to do something like this

```
$scope.DeleteIndicatorConfirm = function () {
    ngDialog.close(modalInstance.id);
};
```

See https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#closeid-value